# Need to remove aliases from list of emails in .csv (powershell)

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, notepad++

I have a .csv with roughly 800 emails in it.  I need to remove the aliases from the address so I can import just the domains.  I also need to remove the duplicates but I can do that myself.

I have tried various forms of the get-content and replace command but am unable to get it formatted right.

So I have a huge list of

alias@domain.com addresses,
I need to parse those to just
domain.com addresses.

This doesn't *have* to be done in Powershell if someone has another (free) option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your .csv look like (are there more fields there than just the email addresses, or is it just a list of addresses)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given a CSV file as such:

```
Name,Email
John Doe,jdoe@company.com
Jane Smith,jane.smith@othercompany.com
Bill Anderson,BigBadBill@hotmail.com
```

You could do this:

```
$EmailList = import-csv emaillist.csv|?{$_.email -match "@.+\..+"}|%{$Matches.values}|select -Unique
```

Or if it is just a list, with no header row or anything such as:

```
jdoe@company.com
jane.smith@othercompany.com
BigBadBill@hotmail.com
```

You could do:

```
$EmailList = gc emaillist.csv|?{$_ -match "@.+\..+"}|%{$Matches.values}|select -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column with emails is the last columns(the furthest right when you open the file, or the only column).
This will return required values:

```
gc YourEmailsList.csv | % {
    [regex]::matches($_,"(?<=@).*\.*[a-z]").value
}
```